# Best Way to Test Promises in Jest

Tags: javascript, promise, jestjs

Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the resolves and rejects (https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#resolves) won't be available until vNext. What is the recommended way now/in the meantime to test promises with Jest? Is it just putting expects in the thens and catches?

For example:

```
describe('Fetching', () => {
    const filters = {
        startDate: '2015-09-01'
    };
    const api = new TestApiTransport();

    it('should reject if no startdate is given', () => {
        MyService.fetch().catch(e => expect(e).toBeTruthy()); // see rejects/resolves in v20+
    });            

    it('should return expected data', () => {
        MyService.fetch(filters, null, api).then(serviceObjects => {
            expect(serviceObjects).toHaveLength(2);
        }).catch(e => console.log(e));
    });            
});
```

**UPDATE 15 June 2019**: Not too long after I posted this question, Jest started supporting this out of the box. I changed the accepted answer below to reflect the currently best way to do this.

**UPDATE 8 Dec 2021**: At some point Jest started supporting async/await. So while other methods noted work, I've taken to simply (for most cases) using something like:

```js
it('should do something', async () => {
    const expected = true; 
    expect(await funcToTest()).toEqual(expected);
});
```

As with most cases, async/await is much more readable than alternatives. The only case I use `resolves` or `rejects` now is for simple cases like:

```js
it('should not throw when doing something', async () => {
    await expect(funcToTest()).resolves.not.toThrow();
});

it('should throw when something is wrong', async () => {
    await expect(funcToTest()).rejects.toThrow();
});
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Nowadays you can write it in this way as well: [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#rejects)

```
describe('Fetching', () => {
    const filters = {
        startDate: '2015-09-01'
    };
    const api = new TestApiTransport(); 

 it('should reject if no startdate is given', () => {
   expect.assertions(1);
   return expect(MyService.fetch()).rejects.toEqual({
     error: 'Your code message',
   });
 });          


 it('should return expected data', () => {
   expect.assertions(1);
   return expect(MyService.fetch(filters, null, api)).resolves.toEqual(extectedObjectFromApi);
 });            
});
```

**Update (06.01.2019)**

Agree that the accepted answer doesn't work correctly as line
`expect.assertions(1);` does all the magic. [Link to docs](https://jest-bot.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#expectassertionsnumber)

> expect.assertions(number) verifies that a certain number of assertions
>   are called during a test. This is often useful when testing
>   asynchronous code, in order to make sure that assertions in a callback
>   actually got called.

So putting this line at the top will control that the specific **number** of assertions are made by the time when the test is run.

Comment: Thanks for an answer that actually works, unlike most SO answers or the Jest docs on async testing.

Answer (score 19):

Either return a promise and expect in the `resolve` or `catch`

```
describe('Fetching', () = > {
  const filters = {
    startDate: '2015-09-01'
  };
  const api = new TestApiTransport();
  it('should reject if no startdate is given', () = > {
    return MyService.fetch()
      .catch (e => expect(e).toBeTruthy()); // see rejects/resolves in v20+
  });
  it('should return expected data', () = > {
    return MyService.fetch(filters, null, api)
      .then(serviceObjects => {
        expect(serviceObjects).toHaveLength(2);
      })
  });
});
```

or using [`async/await`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#async-await)

```
describe('Fetching', () = > {
  const filters = {
    startDate: '2015-09-01'
  };
  const api = new TestApiTransport();
  it('should reject if no startdate is given', async() = > {
    try {
      const r = await MyService.fetch()
    } catch (e) {
      expect(e).toBeTruthy()
    }
  });
  it('should return expected data', async() = > {
    const serviceObjects = await MyService.fetch(filters, null, api)
    expect(serviceObjects).toHaveLength(2);
  });
});
```

Comment: you have to return the promise. Updated my answer with your example

Comment: Thanks. I added the returns for now. I don't see a different results, but I'm assuming that lets the framework know to wait to resolve or something?

Comment: Why does my test still pass but I get a red message saying the expect did not work? I get all tests passing but the result is false to my then expect.

Comment: Sounds like the expect is called after the test is finished. Please ask a new question for your specific problem

Comment: For using `async` I'm pretty sure you need to use the `done()` function and call it manually.

Comment: This will only run the error expectation if the code under test does actually throw an error - if the code is broken, and for whatever reason an exception isn't thrown, the expectation won't run. Yevhenii's answer below avoids this.

Comment: you should add `expect.assertions(1)` at the beginning of reject test. Because the test will pass no matter if the `fetch` fail or not.

Comment: async/await rocks :)

Answer (score 2):

> For additional Jest matchers maintained by the Jest Community check out [`jest-extended`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended).

<sup>https://jestjs.io/docs/expect</sup>

Using [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) you can `expect` your promise **[`toResolve()`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toresolve)** or **[`toReject()`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#toreject)**. Then you can `expect` *the result* or *the error* to match something. For example:

```js
test('OK status', async () => {
  const request = fetch(...)
  await expect(request).toResolve() // First, make sure it resolves
  const data = await request
  expect(data).toEqual(...) // Then test the result
})
test('ERROR status', async () => {
  const request = fetch(...)
  await expect(request).toReject() // First, make sure it rejects
  await request.catch((error) => expect(error).toBe('...')) // Then test the error
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to test JEST with AXIOS for HTTP REST calls like this.

```
it('has an API worth testing', async () => {
  let httpResult = null;
  await callThefunctionThatReturnsPromiseToMakeTheAxiosApiCall()
    .then(function(result) {httpResult=result;})
    .catch(function(err) {httpResult=err;});
  expect(httpResult.data.myData).toBe("myExpectedValue");
});
```

or

```
it('has an API worth testing', async () => {
  let httpResult = await callThefunctionThatReturnsPromiseToMakeTheAxiosApiCall();
  expect(httpResult.data.myData).toBe("myExpectedValue");
});
```