# JestJS: Async test isn't stopped

Tags: javascript, mongodb, testing, jestjs

I got two problems with this jest test:

1. Is it possible to define the `Content` collection only once instead of doing that inside of the test?
2. I do get this error:

   Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.
   This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.

I don't see why my async code weren't stopped...

```
import resolvers from 'resolvers/'
import Db from 'lib/db'
const db = new Db()

describe('Resolver', () => {
  let token

  beforeAll(async () => {
    await db.connect()
  })
  beforeEach(async () => {
    token = 'string'
    await db.dropDB()
  })
  afterAll(async () => {
    await db.connection.close()
  })

  describe('articleGetContent()', () => {
    test('should return dataset', async () => {
      // SETUP
      const Content = db.connection.collection('content')
      const docs = [{
        // some content...
      }]
      await Content.insertMany(docs)
      // EXECUTE
      const result = await resolvers.Query.articleGetContent({}, {
        id: '123,
        language: 'en'
      }, {
        token
      })
      // VERIFY
      expect.assertions(1)
      expect(result).toBeDefined()
    })
  })
})
```

*resolver*

```
import { articleGetContent } from '../models/article'

export default {
  Query: {
    articleGetContent: async (obj, { id }, { token }) => articleGetContent(id, token)
  }
}
```

---

This is how my db class looks like

*db.js*

```
export default class Db {
  constructor (uri, callback) {
    const mongo = process.env.MONGO || 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
    this.mongodb = process.env.MONGO_DB || 'testing'
    this.gfs = null
    this.connection = MongoClient.connect(mongo, { useNewUrlParser: true })
    this.connected = false
    return this
  }

  async connect (msg) {
    if (!this.connected) {
      try {
        this.connection = await this.connection
        this.connection = this.connection.db(this.mongodb)
        this.gfs = new mongo.GridFSBucket(this.connection)
        this.connected = true
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('mongo connection error', err)
      }
    }
    return this
  }

  async disconnect () {
    if (this.connected) {
      try {
        this.connection = await this.connection.close()
        this.connected = false
      } catch (err) {
        console.error('mongo disconnection error', err)
      }
    }
  }

  async dropDB () {
    const Content = this.connection.collection('content')
    await Content.deleteMany({})
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Related to the ***second*** question I hope you've found some issues on github about it. 
 In general, the issue is described in the debug log. 
 Jest works with promises, as a result, you shouldn't leave any async operations in any status except resolved.

In your case, you have your DB connection opened so you need to implement another method `disconnect` for your DB class, [this link to docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#close) will help you, but I guess you have it already as it's not the full db.js file ( I see some custom method `dropDB`. Main idea here is to have it in `afterAll` hook:

`afterAll(() => db.disconnect());`

Great example at the bottom of the [page](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb)

---

What about the ***first*** question, it really depends on what you are doing in your method `dropDB`. If you're running method for [dropping collection](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#dropcollection), you could store the reference to this collection somewhere outside and use it as it will automatically create the new one, but it would be great to see this method.

---

**Additionally**, your async test was created in a wrong way, you could read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037566/best-way-to-test-promises-in-jest/50699931#50699931) for example in my Update. You need to run this function in the beginning of the test: `expect.assertions(number)`

> expect.assertions(number) verifies that a certain number of assertions
>   are called during a test. This is often useful when testing
>   asynchronous code, in order to make sure that assertions in a callback
>   actually got called.

Comment: Unfortunately my DB class seems to be wrong. I updated the code and tried to add the disconnect method, but this is currently failing. I added a `afterAll()` to the test, but still get the same bad result.

Comment: what does it mean `db.connection.close()` ?  
you've opened the connection to DB before all tests and you need to close connection to DB afterAll

Comment: I've sent you a link in post: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/db.html#close